# Display loading screen while loading page with some heavy back end work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, loading

I'm trying to display a loading page while loading up a dashboard page with some graphs and charts (I'm using the Telerik RadHtmlChart Controls for this). The data for these graphs and charts are fetched from a remote API and the queries into the db is quite Heavy, so the API calls can take upwards of 5-6 seconds Before I receive them. All this is done in code behind on the page. So, I would like to implement some form of loading screen while the page is loading. I've tried some jQuery implementations, however the page won't be sent to the user Before the `Page_Load` event is done, which is when all the data has been fetched, which in turn means that there will be no loading image, just a 5-6 wait for the user Before the page shows up.

Is there a nice way around this? Is there a way to render the page and THEN call a function in code behind and have it run and render the charts and graphs then?

Comment: For a dashboard you can load the panels/base UI and show loading image inside each panel as the data/graph is being fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX (A developer dream, as w3schools says xD).

First you should send the page content, without any query done, so the page is sent immediately. Then, the page should make an AJAX query to your server (to an special url for this, or whatever) asking for the info it wants. Meanwhile you could show a loading icon. When the AJAX call returns data, then you can initialize your chart widgets with it.

Depending on how you have your front-end developed, this will be (not) trivial to do, btw.

You can start here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

To clarify:

- You have to change your method that serves the page to not do any query.
- Then create a page that makes the long-query and outputs it without any HTML markup. Just the formatted data to work with your widgets, for example.
- In the front you should move all the script that initializes the widgets to a function.
- Finally, you should add an AJAX query at startup that will call the newly created page, process the data (jQuery has AJAX methods to load JSON directly) and initialize your widgets with this data.